# Rotate an object in SVG

Tags: svg, rotation

I am just getting started with SVG and am now trying out rotating objects.

I have the initial canvas and have created my own drag and drop function so on mousedown the drag is initialized and mouseup it stops. The problem i'm having is when I rotate an object, it seems to change the x and y. This is visible when i'm trying to drag an object. Does anyone know how to get around this so the x and y get "normalized" in relation to the rotate angle?

Here's my code.

```
<svg version="1.1" width="900" height="400"><text x="10" y="10" id="text_0" width="200" height="40" transform="rotate(45, 0, 0)">SVG test</text></svg>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rotate` parameters give you the angle and the center of the rotation (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Attribute/transform) for example). And what about the `width` and `height` attributes in your text anyways? This is not part of the standard as of [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElement). If you want to change the size of your text, do so using `font-size` in the style.

If you want to rotate the text around its (the text element's) center you may use for example the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" width="900" height="400"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <text x="10" y="10" id="text_0" transform="rotate(45, 10, 10)" style="dominant-baseline: middle; text-anchor: middle;">
     SVG test 
   </text>
 </svg>
```

Comment: The width and height attributes was just me messing around. Unfortunately your code did not work for me, it had the same results as last time. From my understanding, the x and y are top left of the object but when the object is rotated the the x and y point moves with the rotation. So shouldn't the style attributes be 'top left' or the equivalent of?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle with your drag&drop code included?

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/pKwkj/2/ There is a lot of rubbish on the page as i'm just testing things. On page load, click on the Text link at the top left corner of the page and you will see some text appear on the left of the screen (it's draggable). The click event which is adding the text object is $('.add.text').click

Comment: Just an idea, I'm not familiar with JQuery SVG. Use an [animateTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Element/animateTransform) element to do the moving instead of the actual text element.

Comment: I'm struggling to get animateTransform to work using the jquery plugin i'm using. I'd like to avoid using that anyway, I just want to change the value on the control. To keep it clean.

Comment: The only thing that made me frustrated was, when you rotate and object, setting it's position with x and y would be difficult. If anyone come across this issue, use `translate` before `rotating` for your transform style.